Why does ASP.NET Core throw error 404 when using policy and no authorization header is provided?
My app has both cookie and JWT authentication schemes and I'm using a policy to handle both:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "JWT_OR_COOKIE";
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions => ... )
    .AddFacebook(facebookOptions => ... )
    .AddJwtBearer(options => ... )
    .AddPolicyScheme("JWT_OR_COOKIE", "JWT_OR_COOKIE", options => 
    {
        options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
        {
            string authorization = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("Bearer "))
                return "Bearer";
            return IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        };
    });

When I test the behavior in Postman, if I provide an invalid bearer token, I get http 401 as expected, but when I don't provide a token at all, then I get an error http 404.
If I were to remove the AddPolicyScheme, the DefaultScheme options and the AddCookie calls, then my app still works with JTW, but the behavior then is that it will always return 401 even when the token is missing.
Similarly, if I call the endpoint in a browser without a cookie, I get redirected to Account/Login?ReturnUrl=, when before I would receive a 401
So why is it that adding AddPolicyScheme changes the behavior of the server when no authorization is present in the request?

It depends on the Authorization header when registered AddPolicyScheme. The 404 shows the redirecting to login page fails when not authorized, you could check the route.
